# IIS Point new subdomain to existing virtual directory

Tags: iis, redirect, subdomain, virtualhost

So Currently I have a site accessible by `http://hostname/myvirtualdirectory/home.aspx` If you go to `http://hostname/myvirtualdirectory` it automatically goes to home.aspx... good!

However when I go to `http://hostname` it gives the IIS start page.

Question 1: 
How do I make this redirect to the virtual directory `myvirtualdirectory/home.aspx`

I have pointed a subomdain `mysubdomain.myurl.com` at the server, everything works pretty much the same if I go to `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/` I get the start page but going directly to `http://mysubdomain.mysite.com/myvirtualdirectory` does go to the home.aspx page

Question 2 
Once I point everything correctly in the answer to question 1 do I need to do anything extra to handle the subdomain?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using IIS 7.0 or above.

Answer to question 1) 
Ensure you have the `HTTP Redirection` feature installed, and then setup a redirct on the root website, details here: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpredirect

Answer to question 2) 
You don't need to do anything extra to handle the sub domain unless you've set up multiple websites on the server, from your question I'm guessing that's not the case.