# How to create a virtual subdomain in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I’ve wanted to use subdomains for sub-sites within a single application for a while now. Basically, instead of setting up multiple sub-sites like this…

http://example.com/shop1.aspx?name=john/

…I wanted this…

http://john.example.com/

I want dynamic subdomain virtually using URL rewrite 
I have no idea how to do this.

-----------UPDATE------

After searching over the internet I got following code.it redirect perfect but not rewriting the URL

my page is- http://domain/mySpace.aspx?una=sunil

```
    <rule name="Redirect to Subdomains" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^mySpace.aspx$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^una=(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}.{HTTP_HOST}" 
        appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

But still not able to resolve it.

Comment: You need to use the web server for this. Where do you host your applications?

Comment: What Version of IIS is available with the server?

Comment: On Godaddy https://in.godaddy.com/help/how-do-i-create-a-subdomain-in-simple-control-panel-2290

Comment: @Michael I am hosting my application on the server. but I need a subdomain virtually using URL rewrite.

Comment: Please check these out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386465/iis-point-new-subdomain-to-existing-virtual-directory

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069278/how-to-set-up-subdomains-on-iis-7

Comment: @Sunny I am not sure if this could be achieved.

Comment: @Sunny the problem is that you have to rewrite something. You will need a domain name to route requests to your website. Theoretically you can rewrite from `domain.com` to `sub.domain.com` but this doesn't have any sense because you can't use `domain.com` in this case.

Comment: @Michael Thank you for your response, now you can check my question i updated it that's what I need.

Comment: @Sunny in face you can use some API from your domain provider / hosting to create DNS records dynamically.

Comment: @Michael can we do it throw url rewriting from web.config file

Comment: @Michael Yes Michael ,  i contacted with domain provider regarding Some API but they don't have it.